# Centre a SKLabelNode on a SKSpriteNode

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, sklabelnode

I have an SKLabelNode that is the child of a SKSpriteNode because I'm trying to create a Button class to create buttons in an easier way. I've tried a couple of things using the anchor point of the SKSpriteNode, but I don't quite understand exactly what is going on. How do I centre the label onto the sprite (it's parent node)?

Comment: If you show what you already tried, it would help us assist you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I actually just figured out how to do it. I set the alignment modes (horizontal and vertical) of the label and it is perfectly centred now no matter what size the label text is! I'll post below.

Comment: @02fentym we wish you would have showed your code solution instead of simply expounding the fact you solved a question you asked without showing the solution.

Comment: I did...it's below. I answered the question myself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I realized how to solve this...here's what i did. Keep in mind that I have a class called Button that is a subclass of SKSpriteNode.

In the Button.m class I have an instance variable called label that is a SKLabelNode. I add the label node as a child to the button then set the horizontal and vertical alignment modes to centre.

```
label = [[SKLabelNode alloc] init];
[self addChild:label];
[label setHorizontalAlignmentMode:SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeCenter];
[label setVerticalAlignmentMode:SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter];
```

Comment: OK, but how do you ensure the outer (sprite) button sprite is going to be big enough for the text?

Answer (score 13):

This will put your label in center of scene in sprite kit:

```
yourLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Center;
yourLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = .Center
```

Answer (score 4):

### Swift 4.2 XCode 10.1

Copy this function into your SpriteKit class:

```swift
func createLabel(text: String) {

    // initialisation
    let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Wicked Mouse")

    // customisation
    label.text = text
    label.fontColor = .white
    label.fontSize = 30.0

    // positioning
    label.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
    label.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
    label.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
    label.zPosition = 1
    
    self.addChild(label)

}
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors' question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.